# glossaries error with *4col styles

Tags: glossaries

I wanted to print out a nomenclature with symbols (i.e. VARIABLE - DEFINITION - SYMBOL form). Below is the MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,onecolumn,draft,a4paper]{book} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[acronym, toc, section, shortcuts, nopostdot, nogroupskip]{glossaries} 
\usepackage{glossary-long}
\newglossary[slg]{symbols}{syi}{syg}{Nomenclature}
\newglossary[ilg]{indices}{iyi}{iyg}{List of indices}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{ECD}{ECD}{equivalent circuit diagram}
\newacronym{RES}{RES}{renewable energy source}
\newglossaryentry{Rx1}
{
  name={\ensuremath{R_{x1}}},
  description={Equivalent series resistance},
  symbol={\ensuremath{\Ohm}},
  sort=Rx1, type=symbols
}
\newglossaryentry{ref}
{
  name={*},
  description={Indicates reference value},
  sort=ref, type=indices
}

\begin{document}
\glsaddall        
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, style=long, title=List of Abbreviations and Acronyms]
\vspace{40pt}  
\printglossary[type=symbols, style=long4col, title=Nomenclature]
\vspace{40pt}  
\printglossary[type=indices, style=long, title=List of indices]
\end{document}
```

The error is:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \Ohm
l.5 ...etentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat{1}}}
%
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed... BLA-BLA-BLA
```

It occurs only with 4cols styles one of which I need for printing out the symbols column.
I also totally don't understand the error. Btw, it doen't occur with *3col styles.

Comment: You need to load a package that defines `\Ohm`. The reason the 3cols styles don't produce an error is because they don't try to use the symbol.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot OMG, thanks a lot. I'd even like to delete this question, but let it be.
Actually, I tried to change the glossary style yesterday late evening, that's why so stupid mistakes.

Comment: Don't worry about it. The `siunitx` and `gensymb` packages both provide `\ohm` and `textcomp` provides `\textohm` if that's of any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @NicolaTalbot mentioned above, \Ohm is not a symbol.
I needed to use symbol={\ensuremath{\Omega}} instead.
Excuses, I was simply too tired yesterday evening for noticing that.
But still may be somebody will do the same stupid mistake, so I keep the question (and close it).